# How to implement chained UI State in the ViewModel in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-viewmodel, clean-architecture

In a fragment I need to display in two different textView the content of two files.

That fragment is connected to the data layer through the ViewModel.

I'm making **two calls** to viewmodel, passing it in each case the names of the files whose information I want to get. The problem is that I only get the information from one of the files in the UI, although I have two different textview.

This is my code:

#### Fragment

```
val termsRequest = FileRequest("raw/terms_202301.json", isNightMode, isVoiceOn = false, false)
mViewModel.loadData(termsRequest)

val privacyRequest = FileRequest("raw/privacy_202301.json", isNightMode, isVoiceOn = false, false)
mViewModel.loadData(privacyRequest)

fetchData()

// ....

private fun fetchData() {
    lifecycleScope.launch {
        repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
            mViewModel.uiState.collect { state ->
                when (state) {
                    is FileViewModel.FileUiState.Loaded -> onLoaded(state.itemState)
                    is FileViewModel.FileUiState.Error -> showError(state.message)
                    else -> showLoading()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// ...

private fun onLoaded(fileItemUiState: FileItemUiState) {
    fileItemUiState.run {
    if(fileItemUiState.allData.fileName == "raw/terms_202301.json"){
        binding?.textTerms?.text=allData.text
    }
        if(fileItemUiState.allData.fileName == "raw/privacy_202301.json"){
            binding?.textPrivacy?.text=allData.text
        }
    }
}

private fun showLoading() {
    //...
}

private fun showError(@StringRes stringRes: Int) {
    Toast.makeText(requireContext(), stringRes, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```

---

#### ViewModel

```
@HiltViewModel
class FileViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val getFileUseCase: GetFileUseCase,
    private val coroutineDispatcherProvider: CoroutineDispatcherProvider
) : ViewModel() {

    private val _uiState = MutableStateFlow<FileUiState>(FileUiState.Empty)
    val uiState: StateFlow<FileUiState> = _uiState

    fun loadData(fileRequest: FileRequest) {
        _uiState.value = FileUiState.Loading
        viewModelScope.launch(coroutineDispatcherProvider.IO()) {
            try {
                val result = getFileUseCase.execute(fileRequest)
                _uiState.value = FileUiState.Loaded(FileItemUiState(result))
            } catch (error: Exception) {
                _uiState.value = FileUiState.Error(ExceptionParser.getMessage(error))
            }
        }
    }

    sealed class FileUiState {
        object Empty : FileUiState()
        object Loading : FileUiState()
        class Loaded(val itemState: FileItemUiState) : FileUiState()
        class Error(@StringRes val message: Int) : FileUiState()
    }
}
```

---

#### FileItemUiState

```
data class FileItemUiState(
    val allData: FileResponse
)
```

In debugging, the data layer correctly reads the contents of both files, but the UI only sticks with the last one.

What is wrong in my code? How can I achieve this in the best way and by implementing a clean architecture?

Comment: Can you paste code of ```FileItemUiState``` ?

Comment: @jayeshgurudayalani I added it at end of the question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are only calling **onLoaded()** once, even though you are calling **loadData()** twice. This is because the **onLoaded()** function is called when the **FileUiState** changes, and the **FileUiState** only changes when the **loadData()** function completes.

To fix this, you need to call **onLoaded()** twice, once for each call to **loadData()**. You can do this by changing the **onLoaded()** function to accept a list of **FileItemUiState** objects, and then calling **onLoaded()** with the list of objects that are returned from the **loadData()** function.

Here is the updated code:

```
private fun onLoaded(fileItemUiStates: List<FileItemUiState>) {
    fileItemUiStates.forEach { fileItemUiState ->
        if (fileItemUiState.allData.fileName == "raw/terms_202301.json") {
            binding?.textTerms?.text = fileItemUiState.allData.text
        } else if (fileItemUiState.allData.fileName == "raw/privacy_202301.json") {
            binding?.textPrivacy?.text = fileItemUiState.allData.text
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have changed `onLoaded()` as per your answer, and in `fetchData()` i have changed this line: `is FileViewModel.FileUiState.Loaded -> onLoaded(listOf(state.itemState))` but it still doesn't work as expected. Maybe it's better to create a new usecase where I command to read several files at once?